# Dynamic memory allocation in C problem

Tags: c

I'm trying to increase memory of a, but realloc doesnt seem to do anything. At 4th number program crashes. It seems also that numbers are put into a[0] even though counter is increased and should be a[counter]. I know I start at a[1], because I'm writing counter itself in a[0] when I'm done inputing.

Translation of printf: Input vector (you end input with any nonnumber character except dot).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef float* vektor;

vektor beriVektor() {
    int counter = 0;
    float zacasna;
    float *a = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float));
    printf("Vpisi vektor (vpis zakljucis s katerim koli nestevilskim znakom razen pike):\n");
    while(scanf("%f", &zacasna)) {
        counter++;
        printf("%d\n", counter);
        printf("%d\n", sizeof(a));
        a = realloc(a, (sizeof(a) + sizeof(float)));
        a[counter] = zacasna;
    }
    if (sizeof(a) == sizeof(float)) {
        return NULL;
    }
    a[0] = counter;
    return a;
}

void izpisiVektor(vektor a) {
    if (a == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        int velikost = sizeof(a)/sizeof(float);
        for (int i = 0; i < velikost; i++) {
            printf("%f", *(a+i));
        }
    }

}

void main(){
    vektor a = beriVektor();
    izpisiVektor(a);

}
```

output:

```
ragezor@ragezor-VirtualBox:~$ ./dn09.o 
Vpisi vektor (vpis zakljucis s katerim koli nestevilskim znakom razen pike):
1 2 3 4
1
4
2
4
3
4
4
4
*** glibc detected *** ./dn09.o: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x09052008 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x6c501)[0x835501]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x71c6d)[0x83ac6d]
/lib/libc.so.6(realloc+0xe3)[0x83af53]
./dn09.o[0x804850e]
./dn09.o[0x8048595]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7)[0x7dfce7]
./dn09.o[0x8048411]
======= Memory map: ========
001c9000-001e3000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 393295     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
001e3000-001e4000 r--p 00019000 08:01 393295     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
001e4000-001e5000 rw-p 0001a000 08:01 393295     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
005d5000-005f1000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 393234     /lib/ld-2.12.1.so
005f1000-005f2000 r--p 0001b000 08:01 393234     /lib/ld-2.12.1.so
005f2000-005f3000 rw-p 0001c000 08:01 393234     /lib/ld-2.12.1.so
0069e000-0069f000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
007c9000-00920000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 393454     /lib/libc-2.12.1.so
00920000-00922000 r--p 00157000 08:01 393454     /lib/libc-2.12.1.so
00922000-00923000 rw-p 00159000 08:01 393454     /lib/libc-2.12.1.so
00923000-00926000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 140607     /home/ragezor/dn09.o
08049000-0804a000 r--p 00000000 08:01 140607     /home/ragezor/dn09.o
0804a000-0804b000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 140607     /home/ragezor/dn09.o
09052000-09073000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7700000-b7721000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7721000-b7800000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b78d9000-b78da000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b78e7000-b78eb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
bfc2e000-bfc4f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Aborted
```

edit:
Thank you. Very good answers from all of you.

Is there any way to find out how much memory space does have vektor a allocated?
Later in the code I check with sizeof(a)/sizeof(float) for number of elements in that array which now I understand is incorect. Luckily I have counter stored in a so i know how much elements i have, but if I wouldn't have that information stored how would I know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `realloc` is incorrect. You are getting the size of a pointer on your machine, not the size of the allocated space so far.

```
float *a = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float));
/* .... */
a = realloc(a, (sizeof(a) + sizeof(float)));
```

So, suppose a `float *` occupies 4 bytes. You will always allocate `4 + sizeof(float)` and eventually you'll step outside. You need to keep track of the number of elements and then:

```
a = realloc(a, sizeof(float) * (el_no + 1));
```

Of course, a nicer form would be:

```
a = realloc(a, sizeof(*a) * (el_no + 1));
```

If you later decide to change the type of `a` you'll be safe this way.

**Edit**

*As a side note*, calling `realloc` for each and every new element might seem like a good deal, but it's slow. You should employ a strategy like "when I run out of space I will double the current used amount" or something in that line.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you think this:

```
if (sizeof(a) == sizeof(float)) {
      return NULL;
}
```

Is doing, it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
 float *a = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float));

 ...
 a = realloc(a, (sizeof(a) + sizeof(float)));
```

the 'sizeof(a)' is always going to return 4(on 32-bit machine, 8 on 64-bit machines).  '[sizeof()](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof)' despite its appearance is NOT a function.  It's an operator of sorts that gives you the size of the variable.  IN this case 'a' is just a pointer.  sizeof will not give you the size of what a is pointing at.

What you need to do is keep a length variable  that keeps track of the number of floats you have in the block allocated by malloc/realloc.

```
  int N_floats = 0 ;
  float *a = (float *)malloc(0) ;
  /* add a float */

  a = (float *)realloc(a, (N_floats+1)*sizeof(float)) ;
  a[N_floats] = 1.0 ;
  N_floats += 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = realloc(a, (sizeof(a) + sizeof(float)));
```

`sizeof(a)` and `sizeof(float)` are both constants (for the most part, `sizeof(anything)` is a constant).  So you're always asking for the same amount of memory here.

Typically you need something along the lines of

```
a = realloc(a, counter * sizeof(float));
```

but

1. You'll need to check this for off-by-one errors: maybe you'll want `(counter + 1)` instead of `counter`, or so.
2. Don't *ever* use `a = realloc(a, ...)`.  Look up how `realloc` reports errors (and what it does with the original memory block in the event of errors) to see why.

See also http://c-faq.com/malloc/realloc.html

Comment: If I understand point 2, realloc allocates additional memory to a and all is good. But when it can't it returns NULL pointer and memory allocated to a is lost therefore creating a memory leak?

Of what I'm not sure if realloc finds memory space somewhere else so it doesn't just add some space but reallocates it totally, does it frees up that space or do you have to do that manually?

Comment: (Your questions are mostly answered in books and documentation, and the C-FAQ entry covers this too.)  @ragezor: Point 2 is that if memory allocation fails, realloc() leaves the original memory block alone.  Then if `a` was your only pointer to that block, you've just thrown away your sole way of getting to it; hence memory leak.  The clearest approach is to put the result from realloc() into another variable, and later assign it to `a` if the allocation was successful.

Comment: Administrivia:  You've asked questions based on DipSwitch's and my answers, so clearly you got something from them.  So how about a little voting on our answers...

Comment: I'm new to stackowerflow so it doesn't let me to vote. Will accept your answers though.
Oh, I can only accept one :/

Answer (score 0):

In short `sizeof(a)` doesn't do what you think it does. The type of `a` is `*float` so it has a very small size.  You need to keep track of the length of the array and multiply that by `sizeof(float)` to get the current size.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get means you have a buffer overflow in your heap segment. This is because at line 15 you do:

```
a = realloc(a, (sizeof(a) + sizeof(float)));
```

sizeof is a macro function it will be determent at compile time not a runtime you should use the counter to calculate the needed size for a new read. Try something like this:

```
a = realloc(a, (sizeof(*a) * (counter + 1))); // +  one for the counter itself
```

Also you need to keep in mind that at line 21 you cast your integer (counter) to and float which will cause the counter to wrap and restart with negative value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int value = 822222233;
    float flt = value;

    printf("equal: %s\nvalue = %d\nflt = %f\n(int)flt = %d", value == flt ? "true" : "false", value, flt, ((int)flt));

    exit(0);
}
```

Output:

```
gcc -m32 -O3 -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 test.c && ./a.out
equal: true
value = 822222233
flt = 822222208.000000
(int)flt = 822222208
```

As you can see your counter will corrupt :)

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean that it wraps itself around? Not that affects my program but I would like to know either way.

Comment: Floats don't store the exact number but they store there value in a  scientific notation this means that if you go beyond the range a float can store because it is rounding. See edit. It is also possible to go beyond a point where the value of the float will actually be negative instead of positive.

Comment: Ok, I suspected something like that. It happens in Java too. I thought counter itself will corrupt, because of C's idea of pointers and whatnot which I'm still little fuzzy about. I've just tested out this and only flt is incorect and value stays the same.